# Which is the better way to provide API in AngularJS library

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I am building a third-party library using AngularJS and I want to provide some API for user to interact with some internal properties/functions. Below are two solutions I'm considering, I want to know if some best practice for such a requirement.

- **Wrap the API in an scope object which can be accessed by the App.**

```js
angular.module('lib', []).directive('libDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      api: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.api = {
        sayHi: function() {
          return 'Hi from lib';
        }
      };
    }
  };
});

angular.module('app', ['lib']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  // to do
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <lib-directive api="lib"></lib-directive>
    {{lib.sayHi()}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

- **Wrap the API in a service which can be injected into the App module.**

```js
angular.module('lib', []).factory('libService', function() {
  var hi = 'Hi from lib';

  // return API
  return {
    sayHi: function() {
      return hi;
    }
  };
});


angular.module('app', ['lib']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, libService) {
  $scope.libHi = libService.sayHi();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    {{libHi}}
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'd say it depends on what the library is used for. If it's anything like a DOM element I'd consider the first alternative, otherwise I'd go for the second alternative. What is it for, if I may ask?

Comment: It's a grid which obviously has UI. Meanwhile I also need to provide API for column sorting/filtering/etc.

Comment: Then I'd go for the first solution you provided. You can always have an `options` value in the DOM element which is set in the controller injecting the directive.

Comment: You mean two-way binding `options` as a DOM attribute and register API on it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.